# ExifTool: How do I use the -@ and -tagsFromFile arguments together?

Tags: exiftool

I'm trying to use the -@ and -tagsFromFile arguments together to remove all metadata except specific tags and then copy those specific tags to the IPTC and XMP headers.

exif2all:

```
# Disable backup file
-overwrite_original_in_place

# Strip all headers
-all=

# Preserve these tags (not working)
-tagsFromFile @ -CreateDate -DateTimeOriginal -Artist -XP*

# Copy EXIF to IPTC
-EXIF:Artist > IPTC:By-line
-EXIF:XPTitle > IPTC:ObjectName
-EXIF:XPComment > IPTC:Caption-Abstract
-EXIF:XPSubject > IPTC:Keywords 
# How do I append EXIF:XPKeywords to IPTC:Keywords?
# -EXIF:XPKeywords > IPTC:Keywords
-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal > IPTC:DateCreated
-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal > IPTC:TimeCreated
-EXIF:CreateDate > IPTC:DigitalCreationDate
-EXIF:CreateDate > IPTC:DigitalCreationTime

# Copy EXIF to XMP
-EXIF:Artist > XMP-dc:Creator
-EXIF:XPTitle > XMP-dc:Title
-EXIF:XPComment > XMP-dc:Description
-EXIF:XPComment > XMP:ImageDescription
-EXIF:XPSubject > XMP-dc:Subject
# How do I append EXIF:XPKeywords to XMP-dc:Subject?
# -EXIF:XPKeywords > XMP-dc:Subject
-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal > XMP:CreateDate
-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal > XMP:DateTimeOriginal
```

ExifTool v9.63 copies the tags to the IPTC and XMP headers, strips the EXIF header completely without any exclusions, and outputs the following error:

```
> exiftool -@ exif2all *.jpg
Ignored superfluous tag name or invalid option: -tagsFromFile @ -CreateDate -DateTimeOriginal -Artist -XP*
```

How do I use the -@ and -tagsFromFile arguments together?